# Cannot Install Templates on VS 2013 Premium Edition

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, vsix, sidewaffle

When attempting to install project templates (for, example [VS SPA Templates](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates))

I get an error that my product is not supported. NOTE that I have VS 2013 Premium, not VS 2013 Pro.

Here is the log:

```
1/1/2014 8:59:09 AM -   Supported Products : 
1/1/2014 8:59:09 AM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
1/1/2014 8:59:09 AM -           Version : [11.0]
1/1/2014 8:59:09 AM -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.VWDExpress
1/1/2014 8:59:09 AM -           Version : [11.0,12.0)
1/1/2014 8:59:09 AM - 
1/1/2014 8:59:10 AM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

How can I install templates on Premium edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install templates using SideWaffle

SideWaffle is [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a16c2d07-b2e1-4a25-87d9-194f04e7a698)